# R - prematurely exiting loop

Tags: r, loops

I am re-asking a question, I have tried to simplify my dataset and give an example of my desired output.  If this is still complicated, feel free to post comments that might help me clarify this.

I have a table where I have grouped features that have similar rt and mz.

```
          orig_feat   mz_mid rt_mid similar_feature
1           f_1 685.4350  466.5             f_1
2           f_2 260.1655  245.0             f_2
185         f_2 260.1665  256.5           f_185
408         f_2 260.1670  239.0           f_408
2334        f_2 260.1650  250.0          f_2334
3           f_3 288.1980  276.0             f_3
7           f_3 288.1990  289.0             f_7
414         f_3 288.1970  275.0           f_414
2181        f_3 288.1980  270.0          f_2181
2969        f_3 288.1965  297.5          f_2969
4           f_4 537.3915  454.5             f_4
2271        f_4 537.3965  435.5          f_2271
5           f_5 439.2990  153.5             f_5
6           f_6 325.0690  210.5             f_6
10          f_6 325.0685  227.0            f_10
747         f_6 325.0685  184.5           f_747
2068        f_6 325.0695  225.0          f_2068
2929        f_6 325.0685  218.0          f_2929
2970        f_6 325.0680  237.0          f_2970
31          f_7 288.1980  276.0             f_3
71          f_7 288.1990  289.0             f_7
4141        f_7 288.1970  275.0           f_414
21811       f_7 288.1980  270.0          f_2181
29691       f_7 288.1965  297.5          f_2969
```

I want to make a list with an entry for each of these groups. All rows with the same $orig_feat should be 'grouped', and for each of these 'groups' I want a vector of all of the features. See example desired output below.

```
    $grf_1
[1] "f_1"

$grf_2
[1] "f_2"    "f_185"  "f_408"  "f_2334"

$grf_3
[1] "f_3"    "f_7"    "f_414"  "f_2181" "f_2969"

$grf_4
[1] "f_4"    "f_2771"

$grf_5
[1] "f_5"

$grf_6
[1] "f_6"    "f_10"   "f_747"  "f_2068" "f_2929" "f_2970"
```

But importantly I want this to be non-redundant (eg. gf_3 : contains f_7,f_414,f_2181,f_2696, therefore when I get to f_7 I will not make a group for f_7 as the f_3 group allready contains all the features in the f_7 group)

Below is my code as it stands.  Currently, the produced output stops after grf_3.
I am not sure why it seems to be prematurely exiting the loop.

```
mkFeatGroupsList<-function(simFeatsTab){
  features_seen<-vector()
  GroupingList<-list()
  counter=1
  for (i in 1:length(unique(simFeatsTab$orig_feat))){
    orig_feat2Grp<-simFeatsTab$orig_feat[i]
    if (orig_feat2Grp%in%features_seen == TRUE) next
    matchingFeats<-subset(simFeatsTab,orig_feat==orig_feat2Grp)$feature
    grFeatNm<-paste("grf_",counter,sep="")
    GroupingList[[grFeatNm]]<-matchingFeats
    features_seen<-c(features_seen,matchingFeats)
    counter=counter+1
  }
  return(GroupingList)
}
```

Incase you need the data for testing.

```
> dput(simFeatsTab.10.30.test)
structure(list(orig_feat = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L), .Label = c("f_1", "f_2", "f_3", "f_4", "f_5", "f_6", 
"f_7"), class = "factor"), mz_mid = c(685.435, 260.1655, 260.1665, 
260.167, 260.165, 288.198, 288.199, 288.197, 288.198, 288.1965, 
537.3915, 537.3965, 439.299, 325.069, 325.0685, 325.0685, 325.0695, 
325.0685, 325.068, 288.198, 288.199, 288.197, 288.198, 288.1965
), rt_mid = c(466.5, 245, 256.5, 239, 250, 276, 289, 275, 270, 
297.5, 454.5, 435.5, 153.5, 210.5, 227, 184.5, 225, 218, 237, 
276, 289, 275, 270, 297.5), similar_feature = c("f_1", "f_2", 
"f_185", "f_408", "f_2334", "f_3", "f_7", "f_414", "f_2181", 
"f_2969", "f_4", "f_2271", "f_5", "f_6", "f_10", "f_747", "f_2068", 
"f_2929", "f_2970", "f_3", "f_7", "f_414", "f_2181", "f_2969"
)), .Names = c("orig_feat", "mz_mid", "rt_mid", "similar_feature"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "185", "408", 
"2334", "3", "7", "414", "2181", "2969", "4", "2271", "5", "6", 
"10", "747", "2068", "2929", "2970", "31", "71", "4141", "21811", 
"29691"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proceeded this way:

- split your data frame (I called it `feat`) by `orig_feat`
- use `sapply` to get the related features
- loop through the related features and eliminate duplicates

Which translates into:

```
feat.split <- split(feat, my.df$orig_feat)

sim.feat <- sapply(feat.split, function(x){x$similar_feature})

for (i in 2:length(sim.feat))
  {
  # Get all of the previous features
  prev.feat <- do.call("c", sim.feat[1:(i-1)])

  # Remove features already used
  sim.feat[[i]] <- sim.feat[[i]][!sim.feat[[i]] %in% prev.feat]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Now after removing the previous features there are some empty elements.  I tried this to remove them, but it doesn't work. Other suggestions? sim.feat<-lapply(sim.feat,function(f) f[length(f)>0] )

Comment: @user2814482: try `sim.feat[sapply(sim.feat, length)>0]`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution can be using the `igraph` package:

```
 require(igraph)
 x<-graph.data.frame(df[,c(1,4)])
 #You can also take a look with plot(x)
 res<-clusters(x)
 split(names(res$membership),res$membership)
 #$`1`
 #[1] "f_1"
 #$`2`
 #[1] "f_2"    "f_185"  "f_408"  "f_2334"
 #$`3`
 #[1] "f_3"    "f_7"    "f_414"  "f_2181" "f_2969"
 #$`4`
 #[1] "f_4"    "f_2271"
 #$`5`
 #[1] "f_5"
 #$`6`
 #[1] "f_6"    "f_10"   "f_747"  "f_2068" "f_2929" "f_2970"
```